# Making Numpad in c# winforms not working

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, keyboard-events

```
private void btnPress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String key = ((Button)sender).Text;
        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(key);
        SendKeys.SendWait(VirtualKeyCode.NUMPAD4.ToString());
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new KeyPress());
    }
```

[image: my form layout]

this thing is not working any help please. When i click on my textbox and click ont button1 then the 1 doesnot appear here.. and text box focus is also lost..

Comment: You can save last focused textBox in textBox_GotFocus event and simply append to its text in your btnPress_Click.

Comment: but dont u think thats a bad approach towards coding. Is it that tough to do?

Comment: @Sirwani - Can you please explain the code inside the button click. The second & third lines precisely.

Comment: if button1 is pressed then the text for 1 and then store 1 in "key" then try to simulate this text into text box

Comment: SendKeys.SendWait(VirtualKeyCode.NUMPAD4.ToString()); was just another hit and trial way from web

Comment: Can't we make button's focus to false. It will then do the job??

Comment: @Mayur i have the same question, did you get any solution, share it please

Answer (score 0):

Well if I get you, you need something like

```
private TextBox _lastFocused; defined in your form
```

then add an OnEnter or OnExit to each participating textbox setting _lastFocused, so you know which control you want the keypress to go to

then in your buttonClick(s)

```
String key = ((Button)sender).Text;
_lastFocused.Focus();
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(key);
SendKeys.SendWait(VirtualKeyCode.NUMPAD4.ToString()); 
((Button)sender).Focus(); // if you want to out focus back the button clicked
```

As far as I can see what is happening is that
Clicking on the button shifts focus from whichever text box your were in to the button.
Sendkeys routes your simulated key press to the currently focused control which is of course your button. So the fix is simply to flip focus back to where you last came from.

Comment: there are many text boxes.. for each text box i have to do it, that will make my job even tough. there would be somthing that gets the current cursor position and have to change the focus if the clicked event is button or something like that